# Probability of die roll for multiple tosses

Tags: probability

We toss  a 6-sided fair die, with sides numbered 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6, for t =10, 50, 100, and 500 tosses.Suppose X is a random variable denoting the outcome of a die toss. Based on the analysis, what is the probability that X has **odd value**?

My Answer - 
P[X=1] = 1/6
P[X=3] = 1/6
P[X=5] = 1/6
P[X =1,3 OR 5 ] = 3/6 = 1/2 is the probability of getting an odd number for 1 toss .
For 10 tosses and so forth  is it : [1/2]^10 ? The number becomes really small . However when i simulate this via a python or mat lab program using random numbers for 10 tosses the probability is 0.40.
How is the theoretical calculation much different than the  python program ?

Answer (score 1):

You do not say whether you want all the rolls to be odd.  If that is true, your $\frac 1{2^{10}}$ is correct for $10$ tosses.  If you want the total of all the rolls to be odd, it is $\frac 12$ and there is something wrong with your code.  No matter whether the total is odd or even after the next to last toss, you have $\frac 12$ chance of getting the right parity on the last toss to make the total odd.